# automatically compute passport expiry js, php, html

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im looking for an answer where I could type a date using HTML tag `input type = "date" name = "Date_issued"`, then it will automatically compute and display it in another HTML tag `input type = "date" name = "Date_expiry"` with the formula of Date_issued + 5years using javascript.
It's all about a passport expiry.
I'm really hoping to had a answer to this and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This javascript should get you going.

```
var d = new Date('2013-09-23'); // The date "issued"
d.setYear(d.getFullYear() + 5); // Add 5 years
document.write(d);
```

Comment: How could i make it yyyy-mm-dd format? dont know the syntax could you also give me a set of video tutorial for javascript? this is much sorry :) but thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript